# why same class file in eclipse not overwriting and showing error type already defined

Tags: java, eclipse

created a "java" class in eclipse, when try to use same class name in same package again it showing error "type already defined". when write program in notepad and running in command prompt it overwriting class and not showing error, why not overwriting when using eclipse, to overwrite what need to do.

Comment: Either replace Files or delete the content inside and paste your new code. You can not create another class file with the same name in the same folder structure

Comment: you could either refactor the old file and change the class as well as the file name for it or just pick a different name for the new class.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Okay, through comments I think we've actually got to the bottom of the problem. The situation is:

- Compiling under Windows
- There are two classes in the same file, with the same name *except* for case
- The command-line compiler doesn't noticed that the two class files will become one due to Windows file system case-insensitivity, but Eclipse does

So as an example:

```
class Foo {}
class foo {}
```

The Eclipse error message also makes this pretty clear, by mentioning case:

> Class file collision: A resource exists with a different case: '/Sandbox/bin/Foo.class'.

As with my earlier answer, my advice is still the same *don't do this*.

---

Earlier answer...

I suspect that when you used the same name in a different file and compiled from the command line, you only specified *one* of them to compile - whereas Eclipse will try to compile all the classes present. If you specified both of the files, you would have got an error:

For example:

```
X.java
class Foo {}

Y.java
class Foo {}

> javac X.java Y.java
Y.java:1: error: duplicate class: Foo
class Foo {}
^
1 error
```

Basically, don't do this. Either rename one of the classes, or delete one of the files.

Comment: no its in same file, and when compile via command line its replacing existing class file with newly created one, but you are right about in the case of eclipse

Comment: @user3877538: If you've got two classes with the same name in the same source file, that should cause a compile-time error in every case - and it does for me from the command-line. It would really help if you'd show a short but complete example in your question, otherwise we're just guessing at what you've actually got. But the upshot is *still* "don't do this".

Comment: think already a class name with student() in a package example/E1, if you create again a class with same name as Student() in same package as example/E1 and compile through command line it will work, will not show  error

Comment: @user3877538: Well for a start, class names don't have brackets in them. And you've given examples with *different* names, but they differ only by case. This is the first time you've mentioned this so far - previously you'd said they were the *same* name. My guess is that you're on Windows, and Eclipse has noticed the problem where the command-line compiler didn't. If you had put a short but complete example in your question to start with, you'd have avoided wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @user3877538: See my edited answer and *please* be more specific when asking questions in future. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: not compile as javac X.java Y.java, think x.java already compiled and after that compile y.java. it is working fine

Comment: @user3877538: No, it's *not* working fine, if those two files both contain the same class name except by case, and you're on Windows... the first class file will basically be lost. Personally, I don't regard losing code as "working fine".  I don't know how many more times I can say this though: **don't do this**. There's no need, no benefit, and *just* problems. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes i am using windows, i am learning java so there are more than 1000 small programs, around 800 programs i've completed by compile through command prompt, so whenever i write program usually use same class name so while executing no problem it replace the existing class file, when i starts using eclipse problem occurred, i could not able to use same class again, so i seek is there any way to use same name for class in same project, thanks for your help advice i hope more help from you

Comment: @user3877538: Either just a separate project, or use an entirely different class name, or just delete the old file. Do *not* use the same class name (with or without the same case) in the same project. It's just a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse would let you create a class with the same name in the same package, it would override the existing file containing the original class.

Eclipse assumes that such an attempt is an error on your part.

You have no reason to do that, since you can simply edit the existing class.